# Stubbing out injected services in AngularJS with Mocha

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner

I have the following service, and am confused about how to stub out the following method calls $firebase(), $asArray(), $add().

My service is as follows:

```
services.factory('Exercises', ['$firebase', 'FirebaseUrl', function($firebase, FirebaseUrl) {
  var Exercises = function (workoutId) {
    this.workoutId = workoutId;
    this.exercises = $firebase(this.getFirebaseRef()).$asArray();
  };

  ...

  Exercises.prototype.addExercise = function (exerciseName) {
    this.exercises.$add({
      name: exerciseName
    });
  };

  ...

  return Exercises;
}]);
```

If it helps, my project was generated with: https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic